# LibGDX/Google Play Services Error

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I have been trying to implement Google Play Services into my LibGDX game, and have been using the real-time Multiplayer APK.

However, after everyone has joined the room through auto-matching, I try to start the game through calling a method to change the screen, but i get the error as followed. Even if i removed the contents of the method, the same error still occurs. Could anyone enlighten me?

Thank you!

The error logged in the console is ,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=10002, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at com.mygdx.game.GSGameHelper.onActivityResult(GSGameHelper.java:76) -->
>   which points to this.game.multiplayerready()

Code as Follows:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int request,int response, Intent data){
    if (request == GSGameHelper.RC_WAITING_ROOM){
        if (response == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED || response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM ){
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, mRoomID);
            activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            BaseGameUtils.showAlert(activity, "Left Room");
        }else{
            BaseGameUtils.showAlert(activity, "Game Starting!");
            this.game.multiplayerGameReady();
        }

    }
    else if (request == GSGameHelper.RC_SELECT_PLAYERS){
        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
            return;
        }

        // get the invitee list
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

        // get auto-match criteria
        Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
        int minAutoMatchPlayers =
                data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        int maxAutoMatchPlayers =
                data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        Gdx.app.log("J", "Jmin" + minAutoMatchPlayers + " Jmax:" + maxAutoMatchPlayers);
        for (String invitee : invitees){
            Gdx.app.log("L" , invitee);
        }
        if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
            autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                    minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
        } else {
            autoMatchCriteria = null;
        }

        // create the room and specify a variant if appropriate
        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
        if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
            roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
        }
        RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);

        // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }
}

public class MacroHardv2 extends ApplicationAdapter {
public void multiplayerGameReady(){
    //gamew.multiplayer = true;
    //Gdx.app.log("EMPEZANDO", "Starting Game");
    //gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
    //dispose();
}
}
```

This is where i initiate the class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver{
private GSGameHelper _gameHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _gameHelper = new GSGameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    _gameHelper.enableDebugLog(false);

    GameHelperListener gameHelperListerner = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    _gameHelper.setup(gameHelperListerner);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();config.useImmersiveMode = true;
    initialize(new MacroHardv2(this), config);
}
```

And The class constructor is as follows

```
public MacroHardv2(ActionResolver actionResolver) {
    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;
    actionResolver.setGame(this);
}
```

Comment: It is so clear that your "game" object is null.

Comment: could you explain a little, sorry I am not really experience in it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call

```
this.game.multiplayerGameReady();
```

But you probably didn't set "this.game" anywhere. Where did you define your "game" object. Can you please show the code block that you define it and also set it, or instantiate it.

So "this.game" is your null object you trying to use.

Comment: oh I didnt realise that i am so sorry!

Comment: I have updated the defininition as shown above. Can i relatively ask how does the android launcher work? It is the one that initiates my main class and this game object is shared by everyone? Why cant i initiate it on my core instead? What does config mean also btw? Thanks!

Comment: Could you also explain after i have set up the ingame screen, do i need to determine who is the host? and only the host can onRealTimeMessageReceived?

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. I still can not see your game object definition. You probably have something like that in your Activity class : "private MacroHardv2 game;"

Comment: Alright sorry about that! Will Create a separate thread for that! Hmm isnt  "private MacroHardv2 game;" like indicating that this class has a attribute game with type macrohardv2?

Comment: But you are using this.game just like a field of this class and your code compiling. Can you make a text search in the class for "game" and spot where it is?